# How to make PostgreSQL to load a C-module that depends on a DLL?

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-c++, dll

I have tried without success to create a C-language function in PostgreSQL from a module that depends on another DLL in Windows.

For example, let's suppose I want to create the `sum`function that adds two numbers returned by the `number`function that is in its own DLL.

The code for `number.h` is:

```
#ifndef NUMBER_H
#define NUMBER_H

#ifdef NUMBER_EXPORTS
#define NUMBER_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define NUMBER_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" NUMBER_API int number();

#endif
```

and the code for `number.cpp` is:

```
#include "number.h"
extern "C" int number() { return 1; }
```

The code for `sum.cpp` is:

```
extern "C" {

#include <postgres.h>
#include <fmgr.h>
#include <utils/geo_decls.h>
#include "number.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

__declspec(dllexport) PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sum);

Datum sum(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    int32 a {number()};
    int32 b {number()};
    int32 result {a + b};
    PG_RETURN_INT32(result);
}

} // extern "C"
```

Suppossing that PostgreSQL is installed on `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5`, I create `number.dll` and `sum.dll` using this `build.bat` file:

```
SET PG_DIR=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5
SET PG_INCLUDES=/I%PG_DIR%\include /I%PG_DIR%\include\server /I%PG_DIR%\include\server\port\win32
CL number.cpp /EHsc /MD /DNUMBER_EXPORTS /LD
CL sum.cpp /EHsc /MD %PG_INCLUDES% /LD /link number.lib
```

Then I copy both DLLs to `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\lib` and write the SQL for creating the function in `sum.sql`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sum() RETURNS void AS
'sum'
LANGUAGE C STRICT;
```

After running `psql -U postgres -f sum.sql`, I get the following error:

```
psql:sum.sql:3: ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/sum.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

Note that this error is different from a "file not found" error. It seems that PostgreSQL finds the file, but does not recognize it as a valid module. However, if I create a static library of `num.cpp` instead and link it against `sum.dll`, then the function is created successfully. In other words, PostgreSQL loads the module only if it contains all the code it needs.

Why is this happening and how could I make PostgreSQL to know about `number.dll` when creating the `sum` function?

Comment: Take a look at `sum.dll` in-place in `lib/` with Depenency Walker (depends.exe), it might be enlightening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the `depends.exe` tool on `sum.dll`. As expected, `number.dll` appears as a dependency, but `psql` refuses to load it.

Comment: No complaints from dependency walker about the dependency, though? I've usually built Pg extensions with msbuild via visual studio; see http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/ . PostgreSQL doesn't care about any extra libraries your extension DLL needs, the operating system is responsible for loading them. `The specified module could not be found.` is an error from Windows's LoadLibrary call, not one generated internally by PostgreSQL. It may refer to your extension `sum.dll` *or any other DLL required by `sum.dll`* and unfortunately doesn't say which

Comment: I read the article and did it by myself. There are some aspects in there I hadn't considered. Howerver, the DemoExtension does not refer to other DLLs, which makes it quite simple. I tried to follow the same steps with my own code, but I still have the same problem. Also, DemoExtension is a C-only example, and I need it for C++. The article says PostgreSQL won't work with C++, but according the documentation it can work by following the C++ extensibility guidelines.

Comment: It's a minimal example. Feel free to submit a more complex sample demonstrating use of other libraries and C++, I'd happily incorporate it. Using other libraries works much like in any other codebase, but if it's a library with a C++ interface you must use it via a C/C++ wrapper/adapter layer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice you were the article's author. Knowing that I would have chosen better words. But I finally found the cause of the problem and the solution.

I didn't know PostgreSQL maintains its own copy of `PATH`, which is loaded at startup. Thus if you change the system's `PATH`, after PostgreSQL is started, it won't have any effect until you restart the server. Also, I was changing `PATH` in the command prompt, but it has to be changed in the System Properties window. I tried this solution with a C++ example and it works as expected.

Comment: That's true of all programs, not just PostgreSQL, and all environment variables. Environment variable changes only affect newly started programs (with a few weird exceptions in some system programs). Thanks for following up with the extra info. Feel free to leave a blog comment to help the next person who gets stuck with the same issue.

Comment: Yeah, it is true for all programs. However, a "common" program started from a command prompt gets the variable values from it. But in this case `psql` (which is also a program) is just a front-end to PostgreSQL (which is a service). So even if I change the variables in the command prompt, `psql` doesn't care about it, although another program could do it. Anyway, this is not a problem for me anymore. And of course, I'll leave a blog comment. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories of the dependent DLLs must exist in `PATH` before PostgreSQL server is started.

Go to:

```
Control Panel
 System and Security
  System
   Advanced System Settings
    Advanced
     Environment Variables
      Path
```

Open it and add the full path of all directories where the dependent DLLs reside. Restart the PostgreSQL server and done, `psql` will execute the C-module successfully.